# C# 7 - Why can't I return this awaitable type from an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, functional-programming, async-await, task

## Background

#### `Try<T>`

The application I'm working in uses a type `Try<T>` to handle errors in a functional style. A `Try<T>` instance represents either a value or an error, similar to how a `Nullable<T>` represents a value or `null`.  Within the scope of functions exceptions may be thrown, but the "bubbling up" of exceptions to higher level components is replaced by "piping" them through return values.

Here is the gist of the `Try<T>` implementation.  The `Error` class is basically equivalent to `Exception`.

```
public class Try<T> {

    private readonly T value;
    private readonly Error error;

    public bool HasValue { get; }

    public T Value {
        get {
            if (!HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return value;
        }
    }

    public Error Error {
        get {
            if (HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return error;
        }
    }

    internal Try(Error error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    internal Try(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        HasValue = true;
    }
}

public static class Try {
    public static Try<T> Success<T>(T value) => new Try<T>(value);
    public static Try<T> Failure<T>(Error error) => new Try<T>(error);
}
```

#### `async`

The application I'm working on is also heavily asynchronous, and uses the standard `async`/`await` idiom.  The codebase exclusively uses `Task<T>`, with no use of plain old `Task` or `async void` methods.  Where you would normally see `Task`, `Task<FSharp.Core.Unit>` is used instead.

As you might imagine, many asynchronous operations may error, and so the type `Task<Try<T>>` gets used a lot.  This works fine, but results in a lot of visual clutter.  Since C# 7 now allows `async` methods returning custom awaitable types, I would like to use this feature to make a class that is effectively `Task<Try<T>>` which can be returned from `async` methods.

#### `TryTask<T>`

So I've created a custom awaitable task-like class (which really delegates most functionality to a `Task<Try<T>>` field), and an accompanying `AsyncMethodBuilder` class.

```
[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(TryTaskBuilder<>))]
public class TryTask<T>
{
    private readonly Task<Try<T>> _InnerTask;

    public TryTask(Func<Try<T>> function)
    {
        if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(function));
        _InnerTask = new Task<Try<T>>(function);
    }

    internal TryTask(Task<Try<T>> task)
    {
        _InnerTask = task;
    }

    public void Start() => _InnerTask.Start();

    public TaskStatus Status => _InnerTask.Status;

    public Try<T> Result => _InnerTask.Result;

    public TaskAwaiter<Try<T>> GetAwaiter() => _InnerTask.GetAwaiter();

    public void Wait() => _InnerTask.Wait();
}

public static class TryTask
{
    public static TryTask<T> Run<T>(Func<Try<T>> function)
    {
        var t = new TryTask<T>(function);
        t.Start();
        return t;
    }

    public static TryTask<T> FromValue<T>(T value) => new TryTask<T>(Task.FromResult(Try.Success(value)));
    public static TryTask<T> FromError<T>(Error error) => new TryTask<T>(Task.FromResult(Try.Failure<T>(error)));
    public static TryTask<T> FromResult<T>(Try<T> result) => new TryTask<T>(Task.FromResult(result));
    public static TryTask<T> FromTask<T>(Task<Try<T>> task) => new TryTask<T>(task);
}

public class TryTaskBuilder<T>
{
    private AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<Try<T>> _InnerBuilder;

    public TryTaskBuilder()
    {
        _InnerBuilder = new AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<Try<T>>();
    }

    public static TryTaskBuilder<T> Create() =>
        new TryTaskBuilder<T>();

    public TryTask<T> Task =>
        default(TryTask<T>);

    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine =>
        _InnerBuilder.Start(ref stateMachine);

    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) =>
        _InnerBuilder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);

    public void SetResult(Try<T> result) =>
        _InnerBuilder.SetResult(result);

    public void SetException(Exception exception) =>
        _InnerBuilder.SetResult(exception.AsError<T>());

    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine =>

        _InnerBuilder.AwaitOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);

    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine =>
        _InnerBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
}
```

## Problem

To make `TryTask<T>` really useful, the first thing I want to do is define functional `let`, `bind,` and `map` higher-order functions that will "unwrap" values and perform operations with them.  Here is an example:

```
public async static TryTask<T2> Bind<T1, T2>(
    this TryTask<T1> source, 
    Func<T1, Try<T2>> binding)
    {
        Try<T1> result1 = await source;

        Try<T2> result2 = result1.HasValue
            ? binding(result1.Value)
            : Try.Failure<T2>(result1.Error);

        return result2;
    }
```

This method will not compile, with the error *CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Try<T2>` to `T2`* on the symbol `result2` in the last line.

If I change the last line to `return result2.Value;` it will compile, but that will not be valid if `result2` has an error.

#### Question

How can I get around this error and get this type to work as the return type of `async` methods?  In typical `async` methods returning `Task<T>`, you can use the statement `return default(T);` and the compiler will wrap that `T` in a `Task<T>` for you.  In my case, I want it to wrap a `Try<T>` in a `TryTask<T>`, but the compiler expects it should wrap a `T` in something.  What method does the compiler use to decide how to do this "wrapping"?

Comment: Have you tried pulling the value of `T2` out of the `Try` and just return that?

Comment: That will compile, but it will ignore the potential for `result2.HasValue == false`.  A `Try<T>` must be returned from the function so that errors can be piped to later functions in a chain of function calls.

Comment: Is `Try<T2>` and `TryTask<T2>` same ?

Comment: To be consistent with the normal `async` syntax, your method declaration would need to return `TryTask<Try<T2>>`. Granted, this conflicts with your desired syntax, but based on the error message, it seems like what the compiler wants. All that said, I'm confused about your desire to reimplement `Task<T>`. After all, `Task<T>` already can either contain a result or an error. What does `TryTask<T>` add to that? Maybe this is just over my head, but I don't see the point.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj No, `TryTask<T>` is basically equivalent to `Task<Try<T>>`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The idea behind the `Try<T>` type is to include the possibility of an error in the return type of operations, rather than "throwing" an exception where "catching" is optional to calling code.  In a sense `Task<T>` is similar, but it is a little inconvenient because its error handling was designed to fit with standard exception throwing.  I want a task that always returns a valid `Try<T>` result (which may contain an error), and never throws an exception.  This unifies error handling inside and outside of tasks, which the default system keeps separate.

Comment: What's the advantage of `TryTask<T>` over `Task<T>`? Both can hold a value or an error and give you access to them.

Comment: Our codebase has a lot of extension methods defined on `Try<T>` which make chaining method calls and using higher order functions very fluent, without a lot of branching to handle error cases, since errors can be piped along.  The idea is that `TryTask` would fit in this idiom better than `Task<Try<T>>` which would sometimes have errors in the `Error` property of the `Result` and would sometimes have errors in the `Task.Exception` property.  It also flattens a very common set of nested generic types which are hard to read.

Comment: Beyond the particular implementation of `TryTask<T>` however, I am really interested in how the compiler decides how to "wrap" the value in a `return` statement in an `async` method into a "wrapped" task-like value.  There is no method in the `AsyncMethodBuilder` convention that represents this wrapping, so what is being done in the normal case of `Task<T>`, and how is the compiler trying to apply this convention to my case?  There is no obvious universal way to wrap a `T` in a `Generic<T>` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this correctly (which is kind of hard without a specification), the root problem is type inference for `async` lambdas, [as described here](https://github.com/ljw1004/roslyn/blob/features/async-return/docs/specs/feature%20-%20arbitrary%20async%20returns%20-%20discussion.md#discuss-genericity-of-tasklike-and-builder) by Lucian Wischik, the original author of the tasklike proposal.

In your case, that would mean something like:

```
void F<T>(Func<TryTask<T>> func) { }

F(async () => Try.Success(42));
```

The lambda returns `Try<int>` and you want the compiler to somehow figure out from that that the type of the lambda should be `Func<TryTask<int>>`. But according to the document linked above, there is no good way to do that.

This is not an issue with your `Bind`, but the language designers chose to have methods and lambdas behave consistently, rather than making methods stronger.

So, as far as I know, what you want to do is not possible. You might consider sharing your use case with the designers of C# by creating an issue at [the csharplang repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang), maybe someone will figure out how to resolve the issues and to make this work in a future version of C#.

Comment: In this case I'm not using lambdas directly.  I see how generalized `async` return types would make type inference for `async` lambdas more difficult though.  Are you saying that the standard "wrapping" of `return T` into `Task<T>` in an async method is being done by the compiler treating the whole method as an `async` lambda and inferring the type?

Comment: @JamesFaix No. What I'm saying is that they couldn't make this work for lambdas, so they decided to not make it work for methods either, for consistency.

Comment: I can see the reasoning there.  Thanks for the link to the design discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, but you may want to consider the [language-ext library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) that has a [delegate based `Try` implementation](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/Try), as well as `Async` variants for all of its extension methods, and a `ToAsync()` extension that converts a [`Try<A>`](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/Try)  to a [`TryAsync<A>`](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/TryAsync).  It also has [`TryOption<A>`](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/TryOption) and [`TryOptionAsync<A>`](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/TryOptionAsync) for returning either a `Some`, `None`, or `Fail`.

```
// Example of an action that could throw an exception
public Try<int> Foo() => () => 10;

// Synchronous Try
var result = Foo().IfFail(0);

// Synchronous Try
var result = Foo().Match(
    Succ: x => x,
    Fail: e => 0
);

// Asynchronous Try
var result = await Foo().IfFailAsync(0);

// Asynchronous Try
var result = await Foo().MatchAsync(
    Succ: x => x,
    Fail: e => 0
);

// Manually convert a Try to a TryAsync.  All operations are
// then async by default
TryAsync<int> bar = Foo().ToAsync();        

// Asynchronous Try
var result = await bar.IfFail(0);

// Asynchronous Try
var result = await bar.Match(
    Succ: x => x,
    Fail: e => 0
);
```

It has a [massive selection of functional types](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes) which if you're implementing types like `Try` you may find useful.

Comment: I started digging into that yesterday actually.  Thanks, very relevant!